# Python create groups of incremented numbers

Tags: python, numbers, increment

In python, I'm trying to generate groups of numbers with defined increments for:

- each group and the next
- first and last numbers in each group (i.e. between the first and second numbers and also between the last and the last but one)
- the remaining numbers of each group

**Example:** (groups containing 6 numbers each)

```
[0, 1, 6, 11, 16, 17], [20, 21, 26, 31, 36, 37], [40, 41, 46, 51, 56, 57], ...
```

Increments in this example:

- between groups: 3
- first and last number in each group: 1
- the remaining numbers: 5

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5     #increment size of remaining numbers in each group
m = 3     #increment size between groups

main = 0.0

for j in np.arange(0, 3):         #the number of generated groups
  for i in np.arange(0, 6):       #how many numbers in each group
    print("{:#.3g}".format(main)) #sig figs
    main += n
    
  main += m - n
  print()
```

Result:

```
0.00
5.00
10.0
15.0
20.0
25.0

28.0
33.0
38.0
43.0
48.0
53.0

56.0
61.0
66.0
71.0
76.0
81.0
```

Question: How to put an extra increment for the first and last number in each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can store the value of the number you want to print in a variable called `main`. As we loop through the group you want to print, we check if it is the first or last number, if so, increment `main` by 1, otherwise, increment `main` by `n`. Add `m` to `main` after a group and print out `main` every time

```
n = 5 # increment size of remaining numbers in each group
m = 3 # increment size between groups
l = 6 # numbers in a group, in your case 6
main = 0 # the number that we print and increases with iterations
for _ in range(10): # this runs for 10 iterations, use while(true) to run forever
    for j in range(l): # loops as many times as numbers in a group
        print("{:#.3g}".format(main)) # print main with sig figs
        if j == 0 or j == l - 2: # if first in group or last, only increase main by 1
            main += 1
        else: # otherwise, increase main by n
            main += n
    print('') # print a new line
    main += m - n # add m to main. n is subtracted because an extra n was added at the end of a group
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a single for-loop and achieved a similar result.

```
import numpy as np

n_groups = 3
group_size = 6
increment_between_groups = 3
increment_within_elements = 5
end_increment = 1

groups=[]
for i in range(n_groups):

    if i < 1:
        initial_element = 0
    else:
        initial_element = groups[i-1][-1]+increment_between_groups
    
    group = [initial_element, initial_element+end_increment]

    group += [increment_within_elements for i in range(group_size-3)]
    group[1:] = np.cumsum(group[1:])
    group += [group[-1]+end_increment]

    groups.append(group)
```

where *n_groups*: number of groups to be formed, *group_size*: number of elements in a group and *end_increment* is the increment at the first and last elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using numpy and want to generate these groups, you might consider generating them all at once rather than with a loop. You can define a pattern that looks like you intervals — something like `[0., 1., 5., 5., 5., 1.]` Then use `np.cumsum()` to build a matrix of values:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5.0     # increment size of remaining numbers in each group
m = 3       # increment size between groups

group_size = 6
num_groups = 3

pattern = np.full([num_groups, group_size], n)
pattern[:,0] = m
pattern[:,-1] = 1
pattern[0, 0] = 0
pattern[:, 1] = 1

# Pattern should look like:
# array([[0., 1., 5., 5., 5., 1.],
#        [3., 1., 5., 5., 5., 1.],
#        [3., 1., 5., 5., 5., 1.]])


# now just take the cummulative sum
pattern.cumsum().reshape([num_groups, group_size])

# array([[ 0.,  1.,  6., 11., 16., 17.],
#        [20., 21., 26., 31., 36., 37.],
#        [40., 41., 46., 51., 56., 57.]])
```

With that you can print, display, modify, etc. as needed.